# SQL Query to find value from set otherwise return a default

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data.

| JobNum | AssemblyNum | OpCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | MF |
| 1 | 0 | Weld |
| 1 | 1 | Eng |
| 1 | 1 | PU |
| 2 | 0 | MF |
| 2 | 0 | Weld |
| 2 | 0 | Paint |
| 2 | 0 | PU-A |
| 2 | 1 | PU-B |
| 3 | 0 | Pack |
| 3 | 0 | Weld |
| 3 | 0 | MF |
| 3 | 0 | PU-C |

The query output should be 1 row per JobNum/AssemblyNum with the build location based on the OpCode. OpCode occurs no more than once in an assembly. If Opcode in ('PU', 'PU-A', 'PU-B', 'PU-C') then return the build location of the code, location not stored in database, otherwise return 'Inhouse'. 'PU' = 'Sub', 'PU-A' = 'Sub A', 'PU-B' = 'Sub B', and 'PU-C' = 'Sub C'

| JobNum | AssemblyNum | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | InHouse |
| 1 | 1 | Sub |
| 2 | 0 | Sub A |
| 2 | 1 | Sub B |
| 3 | 0 | Sub C |

I have tried variations of CASE or IF expressions, but can only return lines that have the PU based operation.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select JobNum, AssemblyNum,
    coalesce(min(case OpCode
            when 'PU'   then 'Sub'
            when 'PU-A' then 'Sub A'
            when 'PU-B' then 'Sub B'
            when 'PU-C' then 'Sub C'
            /* else null */
        end), 'InHouse') as Location
from T
group by JobNum, AssemblyNum;
```

You've stated that only one OpCode can appear per grouping. So a valid code will translate to the correct sub location. If there are none then a null will result and that will then be coalesced into the default value. No alphabetical sorting tricks are necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This did what I needed and not too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a CASE as follows

```
select JobNum, AssemblySeq, "BuildLocation" = CASE
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU'  THEN 'Sub'
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU-A' THEN 'Sub A'
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU-B' THEN 'Sub B'
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU-C' THEN 'Sub C'
        ELSE 'InHouse'
        END 
from  JobOps
```

I get a list of jobs with a Location, no duplicate job/assembly rows, but missing some. I have not gone through the list to check for correct location. But if I add a WHERE clause for a specific Job# and Assembly #, I get 2 rows returned, one with the Sub and the other with the default.

```
where  JobNum='1' and AssemblySeq=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT JobNum, AssemblyNum, 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT CASE
            WHEN OpCode = 'PU' THEN 'Sub'
            WHEN OpCode = 'PU-A' THEN 'Sub A'
            WHEN OpCode = 'PU-B' THEN 'Sub B'
            WHEN OpCode = 'PU-C' THEN 'Sub C'
          END
         FROM docs d2
         WHERE d2.JobNum = d1.JobNum AND d2.AssemblyNum = d1.AssemblyNum AND d2.OpCode IN ('PU', 'PU-A', 'PU-B', 'PU-C')
         LIMIT 1),
        'InHouse'
    ) AS Location
FROM docs d1
GROUP BY JobNum, AssemblyNum;
```

Here is the example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36876e/8

[image]

Comment: Can you use `limit` like that in Sql Server?

Comment: The subquery/join is unnecessary and so is `limit`/`top`. Just use `min` or eliminate the grouping and use `distinct`.

Comment: @shawnt00 I tried both with joins and distinct grouping, but I had the wrong Locations mapping then. Will appreciate if you share the working example

Comment: I had slightly misunderstood how the OpCodes work but my answer is valid using just a simple `group by`.

Comment: @shawnt00 see now, thank you! IMO your example is the most elegant for now

Answer (score 0):

You could consider something like this ([see Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PtQ5iKtu)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT JobNum, AssemblySeq, CASE
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU'  THEN 'Sub'
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU-A' THEN 'Sub A'
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU-B' THEN 'Sub B'
        WHEN OpCode = 'PU-C' THEN 'Sub C'
        ELSE 'InHouse'
        END BuildLocation
FROM JobOps j1
WHERE opcode in ('PU', 'PU-A', 'PU-B', 'PU-C')
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM JobOps j2 WHERE j2.JobNum = j1.JobNum AND j2.AssemblySeq = j1.AssemblySeq AND j2.opcode in ('PU', 'PU-A', 'PU-B', 'PU-C'))
```

This uses your current `CASE` statement, but the `WHERE` condition only returns non-default rows or rows where there `exist` no non-default rows. This `WHERE` condition does return more than one default row for the jobnum=1 and assemblyseq=0 case, but the `DISTINCT` cleans it up.

Answer (score 0):

So first I tried CASE like mchernecki but I noticed it returned both inhouse and sub for each Job/Assembly combination. To combat that, I wrapped it in a cte, used a second cte to add a row number ordered by location, and then returned all rows where row number = 1.

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT 
   DISTINCT JobNum,
            AssemblyNum,
            CASE OpCode 
                 WHEN 'PU'   THEN 'Sub'
                 WHEN 'PU-A' THEN 'Sub A'
                 WHEN 'PU-B' THEN 'Sub B'
                 WHEN 'PU-C' THEN 'Sub C'
                 ELSE 'InHouse'
             END AS Location
        FROM temp
  ),
cte2 AS
  (SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNum, AssemblyNum ORDER BY Location desc) RN
     FROM cte
  )
SELECT JobNum,
       AssemblyNum,
       Location
  FROM cte2
 WHERE rn = 1
```

It might not be the most elegant solution but it works. - [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FbtM2Wgb)

| JobNum | AssemblyNum | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | InHouse |
| 1 | 1 | Sub |
| 2 | 0 | Sub A |
| 2 | 1 | Sub B |
| 3 | 0 | Sub C |

Comment: This hinges on the alphabetical sorting of locations. Should somebody want to change 'InHouse' to 'Us' then the row numbering sort would need to be reversed.

Comment: I can't build a query for something someone might do in the future. Currently, after the CASE, the only locations are Sub something and InHouse. Sort descending puts them in the correct order.

Comment: I've had a moment to think about this and I'm confused about your issue with my query. The InHouse result is created in this query. It is also created in all of the other answers posted. Based on that, it seems your problem with my query is if someone decided to make a change to my query, they would have to change my query?

Comment: Tom, you very much can future-proof software and relying on the alphabetical ranking of  output values is very much the kind of thing that would trip somebody up down the road. It's certainly worth pointing out for sure. I'm saying that an apparently trivial change ought not become unnecessary query surgery.

Comment: I cannot disagree with you more on this. Your 'trivial change' scenario of changing inhouse to us would require every query in every answer in this thread to be changed to meet the new requirement.  You don't like the alphabetic sorting and under different circumstances, I might agree but the values being sorted here are not random. They are controlled in the case expression. I stand behind my answer. It meets the requirements laid out in the original post.

Comment: My answer does not depend on sorting. It does assume that there is only one valid "PU" code per grouping. We do not know if value "InHouse" is significant internally or is only for display purposes where it might even need to be translated to other languages. I would also add that sorting is generally an expensive option from an optimization standpoint.